# Link Aggregation Control Protocol using Opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight, sdn

I'm trying to implement Link aggregation control protocols using Opendaylight controller by following this [guide](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/link-aggregation-control-protocol-user-guide.html) :

On mininet i already running the network topology, configuring the bonding.
On the opendaylight i already running karaf and several feature needed to implement LACP.

The problem is when i already reach this step, 
[dump-groups command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpajQ.png)

the dump-groups command doesnt recognized. Attached the the error announcement image.
[dump-groups unknown command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtRYU.png)

I hope you can help me solve this problem guys. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved, the problem arise because the openvswitch version in my mininet VM is the old version.
After upgrade the openvswitch became version 2.3.1 the problem solved.

Thanks all.